# How to do boolean indexing but assign both subsets to a variable at once?

Tags: pandas

Suppose that we have a dataframe with one column: Number.

By doing:

```
df_that_meets_condition = df[df.Number > 5]
```

we are going to have a df called `df_that_meets_condition` that has all the rows that meet the condition.

How can we assign the subset that does not meet the condition to another variable (suppose `df_that_does_not_meet_condition`) in one line?

An obvious way would be to just another line below with the reversed condition, but I'd like to have one line.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit trick, but possible:

```
df_that_meets_condition, df_that_does_not_meet_condition = df[df.Number > 5], df[df.Number <= 5]
```

Or better is reuse existing mask:

```
m = df.Number > 5
df_that_meets_condition, df_that_does_not_meet_condition = df[m], df[~m]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-liner would be:

```
df_that_meets_condition, df_that_does_not_meet_condition = df[df.number>5], df[~(df.number>5)]
```

Comment: yeah made the changes